# Do we have any control over VoiceOver in iOS for hybrid cordova app?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, voiceover

I have a cordova iOS app. When VoiceOver is active, I have few issues like cursor is not pointing to the top left while navigating between screens(it is pointing to the middle of the screen when navigated to next screen). Also I have few disabled elements, even it speaks disabled elements. How to avoid speaking of disabled elements when VoiceOver is active?
Also is there any way I can add instructions for particular element(like scroll to visit more options)?

Comment: It should read disabled elements.  Just because elements are "disabled" doesn't mean they aren't informative.  If they are visible and disabled, VoiceOver should focus them, and announce them as "dimmed".